# Como aninhar um rota

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources

Boa tarde,

Eu tenho uma ordem de serviço e preciso gerar um laudo através dela, este laudo precisa receber o número da ordem de serviço para salvar na coluna order_id.
Estou tentando fazer uma rota aninhada:

Minha rota esta desta maneira:

```
resources :orders do
    resources :vegoor_reports, only: [:create]
end
```

Na pagina de show da minha ordem de serviço tenho o caminho:

```
<%= link_to 'Laudo', order_vegoor_reports_path(@order), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Tenho as seguintes rotas para orders:

> order_vegoor_reports POST   /orders/:order_id/vegoor_reports(.:format) vegoor_reports#create

Quando vou no botão de Laudo acontece o seguinte erro:

> No route matches [GET] "/orders/1/vegoor_reports"

Alguém conseguiria me apontar onde estou errando?
Obrigado

Comment: Olá Eduardo, esse link_to é para criar um laudo ou para ir para o formulário de criação de um laudo?

Comment: Este link to é para criar o formulário que cria o laudo.

Comment: deixei uma resposta, caso não entendeu ou não era isso que precisava me diz que eu faço a alteração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você citou no comentário, esse link é para ir para a página de criação do Laudo, então está faltando a rota/método 'new'. Por esse motivo retorna o erro, pois você está tentando fazer um GET para uma rota que não existe, o que existe é somente o POST para o método 'create'.

Poderia fazer algo assim:

```
resources :vegoor_reports, only: [:new, :create]
```

E no controller:

```
def new
  @vegoor_report = VegoorReport.new
  # do something
end
```

Assim, você primeiro faria um GET que renderiza a view do formulário(new.html.erb) do VegoorReport e depois que preencher o formulário faz o POST para o método 'create'.

Deu para entender?

Comment: Bom dia Henrique,
Obrigado pelo seu retorno, fiz a modificação e funcionou e estou conseguindo acessar o formulário para criar um novo laudo.
Muito obrigado.